# Multilple plugin loading

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi

I've noticed that it is not possible to load more than one time a plugin

e.g., if I want to use the "rubble plugin" to generate rubble in two different areas, I can't load it two times, even if I change the "name" attribute

possible workaround are:

- copy the library.so with a different name
- write my own plugin and manage multiple zones

If it is not so complicated I think that multiple loading of plugins may be an interesting feature

what do you think?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1817/multilple-plugin-loading/) by [SImone](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/207/simone/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 33 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Sounds like we need to fix this. Thanks for reporting the bug. Here is a ticket: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/587/multiple-plugin-loading

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GAugusto](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/274/gaugusto/) on 2013-03-28**:
hello. was facing the same problem today. is there an estimated time for the bug to be fixed?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-04-11**:
Late summer at the earliest. Of course this is an open-source project so you are highly encouraged to tackle this problem yourself.